# Power cycle micro sd card in android

Tags: android

I am trying to simulate the eject/insert of micro sd card using an android app.  With a rooted kernel and umount/mount, does not help.  Seems umount/mount commands does not do a power cycle on the card controller.

Any help or pointers will be very helpful.

Device:  Samsung Galaxy S II

Thanks in advance,
BTR Naidu

Comment: Research so far suggests that I should implement my own driver or modify the existing driver ending up with a custom kernel.  Not funny :-(.

Answer (score 0):

Have accomplished this by adding my own ioctl commands in MMC driver stack and issuing these command from a user side executable.  Steps to write your own executable is documents in my [personal blog](http://www.btrnaidu.com/index.php/building-own-executable-in-android/).